# jquery child selector without parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I was looking at some code from a tutorial for creating a carousel menu and noticed parent child selectors without the parent. Never seen this before, and confused to what it is actually doing.

See following code:

```
        var $wrapper = $('> div', this).css('overflow', 'hidden'),
        $slider = $wrapper.find('> ul'),
        $items = $slider.find('> li'),
        $single = $items.filter(':first'),

        singleWidth = $single.outerWidth(), 
        visible = Math.ceil($wrapper.innerWidth() / singleWidth), // note: doesn't include padding or border
        currentPage = 1,
        pages = Math.ceil($items.length / visible);
```

Tutorial here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a parent(or in this case a `scope`), notice the `this` keyword inside the selector, that's relative to the element the plugin is being applied to.

jQuery's selectors allow you to set a scope, and it can be any jQuery element object.

**Consider**

```
$(".somediv").myplugin();
```

**And inside the plugin**

```
$("> div", this) 
is actually translated to 
$("> div", $(".somediv"))
```

Have a look at one of my questions, the answer explains quite a bit about jQuery's selectors.
[What is the fastest method for selecting descendant elements in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177763/whats-the-fastest-method-for-selecting-descendant-elements-in-jquery)

Answer (score 7):

This selector with a context:

```
$('> div', this)
```

gets flipped around to use a [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) like this:

```
$(this).find('> div')
```

which with the [`>` child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) is just:

```
$(this).children('div')
```

The others are doing the same deal, they could use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), and actually it'd be more efficient to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('> div', this)
```

The `this` is important. It's a context parameter that makes the query equal to

```
$(this).children('div');
```

See [the documentation for `$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for more information; it specifically mentions this:

> Internally, selector context is
>   implemented with the .find() method,
>   so `$('span', this)` is equivalent to
>   `$(this).find('span')`.

`$(this).find('> div')` means "the `div`s that are children of `this`, which is equal to `$(this).children('div')`.