# What does jquery selector that start at '>' means?

Tags: jquery, selector

Hi i saw selector that is 'parent > child', but didn't see selector that start at '>' 
What does it means?

below this code..

```
    $cb.on('change', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('> tbody > tr > td:first-child > input:checkbox', $bTable).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('> tbody > tr > td:first-child > input:checkbox', $bTable)` this translates into this:

`$($bTable).find('> tbody > tr > td:first-child > input:checkbox')`

The `$bTable` variable is the context in this case for jQuery selector `$()`.

Check this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3497900/9748618

Comment: I originally upvoted, but then you added a link to a duplicate.  The question should be marked/flagged as a duplicate if there's already an answer elsewhere in SO.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case the second parameter of the selector function gives the Context. So the selector selects the first level child tbody from the Context, which is in the $bTable variable

Answer (score 1):

it selects only first-level descendants.
FYI 
[Official Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question; OP already knows purpose of child selector but is asking what (if any) significance it has when it is missing the 'parent'.