# JQuery selector help

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, descendant

Using JQuery, how do I select all elements with class x within an element with id y?

Comment: what do you want to do with these elements? Just select them?

Comment: Shouldn't an id always be unique?

Comment: @Catfish No, but I know how to do the rest. I'm just getting confused with the selecting.

Comment: @John It seems like you're confused about my question. I have an element with id y. There are many elements that are children of that element. Some of the children have a class X. I want to select all the children with class X.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read the question.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177763/whats-the-fastest-method-for-selecting-descendant-elements-in-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selecting all descendants with class x of an element with the id "y".

```
$("#y .x").each(function () {
   $(this) <- your element
});
```

Selecting all childrens with class x of an element with the id "y".

```
$("#y > .x").each(function () {
   $(this) <- your element
});
```

Comment: The first code is the same as `$("#y").find(".x")` and the second is the same as `$("#y").find("> .x")`

Comment: @BrunoLM +1 Good addition, I prefer my method, though. Also, if he wants to do ex `.click` instead, then `.each` is removed anyway.

Answer (score 5):

`$('#y .x')` should do it for you.

note that this will select all descendants with class x, not just children.

Comment: +1 for brevity (Ironic that I can't just put that as a comment: "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.")

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#x .y").doSomething();

$(".y", "#x").doSomething();

$("#x").find(".y").doSomething();
```

And for immediate children:

```
$("#x > .y").doSomething();

$("#x").children(".y").doSomething();
```

Have a look at my question here, it tells you a bit more and it covers performance.
[What is the fastest method for selecting descendant elements in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177763/whats-the-fastest-method-for-selecting-descendant-elements-in-jquery)

Comment: +1 - Thorough answer. Just thought I'd point out that in your second example, you don't need to pass a jQuery object for the context. You could just pass the string `"#x"`. jQuery flips it around into your third version behind the scenes. :o)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$("#id .class")`

Answer (score 1):

Where you have element 1 with id='y' and you want all it's [immediate] children that have a class='x'

```
$("#y > .x").each(function(){stuff]);
```

If you want all decendants of id='y' (not just immediate) then you would do:

```
$("#y").find(".x").each(function(){stuff});
```

Obviously, you could make it smarter (and better) by adding element types if you know what they are. For example, if you want only children of type  then:

```
$("#y > a.x").each(function(){stuff]);
```

Hope that's what you meant.

Comment: Using `.children()` doesn't give you all descendants. Just immediate. You're thinking of `.find()`, which will return all matching descendants.