# replace link with its href using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a p tag that has many anchor tags and some text. i want to replace each of the anchor tags with its respected href.

Comment: could you flesh out your question a little? An example of input and expected output would help a lot.

Comment: @Mat - The following is what the question describes: Input `<p><a href="blah">yada yada</a></p>` ------ Output `<p>blah</p>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I interpret your question that you want to replace the *whole tag*, not only the contained text, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/xXmWj/1/

You are looking for [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$('p a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: @Felix, I was typing this answer! You're a speed demon.

Comment: Definitely cleaner than my answer. +1

Comment: it only replaces few of the anchors and leave others. it shows an error : fragment.childNodes is undefined

Comment: @Yassir: Could you please show this part of your HTML? Could it be that some anchors have no `href` attribute? You might try changing the selector to `$('p a[href]')` and/or changing the return value to: `document.createTextNode($(this).attr('href'));`. Unfortunately I don't know what this error means in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('p').find('a').each(function ()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.attr('href'));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B7AD4/)

Comment: Rather than use find, why not let sizzle do what it does best and use `$('p a')`

Comment: @Phil: because they're semantically equivalent, but `.find()` is faster.

Comment: @Phil: `$("p a")` pretty much gets translated into `$("p").find("a")`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177763/what-is-the-fastest-method-for-selecting-descendant-elements-in-jquery

Comment: This doesn't replace the `a` tag with the contents of the `href` attribute. It just sets the `innerHTML` of the `a` tag to the `href`.... not the same thing.... the `a` tags are not replaced like asked for in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS3** solution without using jQuery:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a > span { display: none; }
    a:after { content: attr(href); }
</style>
<a href="http://www.test.com"><span>Test</span></a>
```

gracefully degrades for non-CSS3 browsers.

Comment: Doesn't appear as though the `:after` pseudo selector is supported before IE9. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15

Answer (score 0):

Pretty similar, I know...

```
$("a").each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).attr('href'));
});
```