# Difference between ways of selecting descendants

Tags: jquery-selectors

With the risk of being redirected to a dublicate question, what is the difference between using $("ul li") and $("ul").find("li")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this similar question of interest:  [What is the fastest method for selecting descendant elements in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177763/what-is-the-fastest-method-for-selecting-descendant-elements-in-jquery)

If you only need first level children, using `.children()` will give you a performance boost since there is less to interrogate.

Comment: Excellent article - that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

`$("ul").find("li")` is faster than `$("ul li")`.

`$("ul li")` is going to be changed into `$("ul").find("li")` after some checks and breaking.

find() appeared faster than children() to me in single level selections.