# How can I access descendants using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have only one ID (main).

I'm trying to set .css() to "main[0]->sub[0]->left[0]" as you can see below:

```
<div id="main">

    <div class="sub">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="subsub">
                main[0]->sub[0]->left[0]
            </div>
            <div class="subsub">
                main[0]->sub[0]->left[1]
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            main[0]->sub[1]
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sub">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="subsub">
                main[1]->sub[0]->left[0]
            </div>
            <div class="subsub">
                main[1]->sub[0]->left[1]
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            main[1]->sub[1]
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I can access the first MAIN child this way:

```
$($('#main').children()[0]).css('MY CSS...');
```

And the second MAIN child this way:

```
$($('#main').children()[1]).css('MY CSS...');
```

But how can I access "sub" class children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every jQuery element has the `$.children()` method.  So you can do `$($($('#main').children()[0]).children[0]).css()`

However, if it's the same set of CSS rules being applied to the elements you can do `$("#main .left .subsub").css()`

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of .find and :first selectors.

```
$('#main').find(".subsub:first")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sizzle selector that could find the first child of both:

`$('#main .sub .left :first-child').css('color', 'red');`

That's not the most efficient (or only selector), as `$('.subsub:first-child').css()` would work as well. Depending on how many times you're doing this, it could be more efficient to cache the parent and use `.children()` per [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177763/what-is-the-fastest-method-for-selecting-descendant-elements-in-jquery)