# jQuery; Check if object has child $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder how I in the best way can see if a container div contains a child element. I have a click event that fires on a child of either div id=unread or div id=read. I want to check where this child is.

Something like this is what I'm thinking:

```
if ($("#unread").find($(this)))
    alert("unread");
else
    alert("read");
```

Edit:
$(this) is a descendants two levels from #unread or #read.

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make use of : [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
if( $("#unread").children().length > 0)
    alert("unread");
else
    alert("read");
```

EDIT

```
if($(event.target).closest('#unread').length > 0)
    alert('unread');
else
    alert('read');
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say that $(this) is a descendants two levels from #unread or #read. So the parent of the parent of this should be either unread or read

Comment: This don't work, since the clicked $(this) is two levels from #unread. It's also not the single child two levels from #unread.

Answer (score 3):

I think just adding `.length` should work:

```
if ($("#unread").find($(this)).length > 0)
    alert("unread");
else
    alert("read");
```

Comment: There are multiple childs looking like $(this), that is two levels from #unread or #read. Therefore children will not identify $(this), i guess.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: the OP asks how to check if one div is a (grand)child of another, not to just check if one div has any children at all.

Comment: @nnn- yes, **now** it says that

Comment: it *always* said that: the second and third sentences and the example code make it clear the click event is on the descendent div and the question is how to figure out which ancestor it belongs to; the edit just clarified that the relationship is exactly two generations apart.

Answer (score 2):

Go backwards from `$(this)` to look for `#unread` as an ancestor using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest):

```
if($(this).closest('#unread').length > 0)
    alert('unread');
else
    alert('read');
```

Depending on your HTML structure, this will be faster than searching all the children of `#unread` to find `this`. The speed difference probably won't matter that much though but you should be aware of the option of going backwards and the possible benefits of doing so.

Checking for the ancestor might be a better match for your intent as well: you have `this` in hand and what you really want to know is "is it inside `#unread`?". Using `closest` to go back up the DOM tree exactly matches the question you're asking.

If for some reason you're dead set on starting at `#unread` and looking at its descendants, then you can use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
if($('#unread').find(this))
    alert('unread');
else
    alert('read');
```

But this approach will only work if you're using at least jQuery 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.closest()` or `.parents()` to search up the tree from the clicked element:

```
if ($(this).closest("#unread").length == 1)
   // etc
```

Otherwise, are you interested in a non-jQuery answer? Given you've said the div with the click event is exactly two levels below the "read" or "unread" divs you could just do this:

```
if (this.parentNode.parentNode.id === "unread")
   alert("unread");
else
   alert("read");

// or just alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder how I in the best way can see if a container div contains a child element.

Use [`$.contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/), especially if performance is a concern. From the docs:

> jQuery.contains( container, contained )
>
> *Returns: Boolean*
>
> **Description:** *Check to see if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element.*

It's more efficient than `.find()`, `.children()`, or `.closest()`, as others have recommended. Be aware, however, that it only accepts DOM elements as parameters, not jQuery objects (which is part of why its performance is better).

In your case, you could do this in your click event handler:

```
if ($.contains($("#unread")[0], this)) {
    alert("unread");
} else {
    alert("read");
}
```

**EDIT:** Upon thinking about this again, it's probably more intuitive to search up from the clicked element, rather than down from the parent element, and performance wouldn't normally be a concern in a click event handler. That is, I would opt to use the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method (as suggested by @nnnnnn and @mu is too short), so my click event handler would contain:

```
if ($(this).closest("#unread").length > 0) {
    alert("unread");
} else {
    alert("read");
}
```