# On select change, get data attribute value

Tags: jquery

The following code returns 'undefined'...

```
$('select').change(function(){
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});

<select>
    <option data-id="1">one</option>
    <option data-id="2">two</option>
    <option data-id="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is it better to use $(this).find(':selected') or $(this).children('option:selected') ?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery

Answer (score 838, accepted):

You need to find the selected option:

```
$(this).find(':selected').data('id')
```

or

```
$(this).find(':selected').attr('data-id')
```

although the first method is preferred.

Comment: i mistakenly used attr() in my inital post, i meant data() but it returns 'undefined' for me.

Comment: I've just come across this and I am wondering if the first method is preferred due to performance reasons, or another reason? @JordanBrown

Comment: @Clarkey my guess would be that data() is faster than attr() because attr() has to do extra work to figure what type of attribute it is. Just a guess tho.

Answer (score 44):

Try the following:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  alert($(this).children('option:selected').data('id'));
});
```

Your change subscriber subscribes to the change event of the select, so the `this` parameter is the select element. You need to find the selected child to get the data-id from.

Comment: As of 2016 `find()` is much faster than `children()` even in cases like this one where we only have a tree depth of 2.

Answer (score 19):

```
document.querySelector('select').onchange = function(){   
   alert(this.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-attr')); 
};
```

Comment: Please always endeavor to support your posted code block with explanation and/or references (even if the solution is simple / "self-explanatory") on StackOverflow because not everyone is familiar with a given language's syntax / behavior / performance.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe a more elegant way

```
$('option:selected', this).data('id')
```

Answer (score 14):

```
$('#foo option:selected').data('id');
```

Comment: Please always endeavor to support your posted code block with explanation and/or references (even if the solution is simple / "self-explanatory") on StackOverflow because not everyone is familiar with a given language's syntax / behavior / performance.

Comment: The OP does not have an `id` attribute on the select element (and doesn't need one because of the utility of `this`).

Comment: this works with select2 library also

Answer (score 10):

Vanilla Javascript:

```
this.querySelector(':checked').getAttribute('data-id')
```

Comment: Please always endeavor to support your posted code block with explanation and/or references (even if the solution is simple / "self-explanatory") on StackOverflow because not everyone is familiar with a given language's syntax / behavior / performance.

Comment: Don't know why, but no jquery solution worked, this one did :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `context` syntax with `this` or `$(this)`.  This is the same effect as `find()`.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
    console.log('Clicked option value => ' + $(this).val());
    <!-- undefined console.log('$(this) without explicit :select => ' + $(this).data('id')); -->
    <!-- error console.log('this without explicit :select => ' + this.data('id')); -->
    console.log(':select & $(this) =>    ' + $(':selected', $(this)).data('id'));
    console.log(':select & this =>       ' + $(':selected', this).data('id'));
    console.log('option:select & this => ' + $('option:selected', this).data('id'));
    console.log('$(this) & find =>       ' + $(this).find(':selected').data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option data-id="1">one</option>
    <option data-id="2">two</option>
    <option data-id="3">three</option>
</select>
```

As a matter of microoptimization, you might opt for `find()`.  If you are more of a code golfer, the context syntax is more brief.  It comes down to coding style basically.

Here is [a relevant performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18222210/2943403).

Answer (score 7):

this works for me

```
<select class="form-control" id="foo">
    <option value="first" data-id="1">first</option>
    <option value="second" data-id="2">second</option>
</select>
```

and the script

```
$('#foo').on("change",function(){
    var dataid = $("#foo option:selected").attr('data-id');
    alert(dataid)
});
```

Comment: Please always endeavor to support your posted code block with explanation and/or references (even if the solution is simple / "self-explanatory") on StackOverflow because not everyone is familiar with a given language's syntax / behavior / performance.

Answer (score 1):

By using this you can get the text, value and data attribute.

```
<select name="your_name" id="your_id" onchange="getSelectedDataAttribute(this)">
    <option value="1" data-id="123">One</option>
    <option value="2" data-id="234">Two</option>
</select>

function getSelectedDataAttribute(event) {
    var selected_text = event.options[event.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    var selected_value = event.value;
    var data-id = event.options[event.selectedIndex].dataset.id);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 alert($(this).first().data('id'));
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post