# How to get data-value of selected option on select change in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

My html syntax is as below

```
<select id="category" name="category">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option value="50" data-value="akne">ACNE</option>
  <option value="11" data-value="rednessbumps">Redness / Bumps</option>
  <option value="15" data-value="sunspotsfreckles">Sunspots / Freckles</option>
  <option value="16" data-value="agingwrinkles">Aging / Wrinkles</option>
  <option value="17" data-value="dry-sensitive">Dry Sensitive</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#category").change(function () {
  var selectedItem = $(this).val();
  var abc=$(this).attr("data-value");
});
```

Here I am not able to get the `data-value` in jquery, How should I get that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Comment: Did you mean selected item's data-value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On select change, get data attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345666/on-select-change-get-data-attribute-value)

Comment: try `var abc = $('option:selected',this).data("value");`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
var abc = $('option:selected',this).data("value");
```

Try

```js
$("#category").change(function() {
  var selectedItem = $(this).val();
  var abc = $('option:selected',this).data("value");
  alert(abc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category" name="category">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option value="50" data-value="akne">ACNE</option>
  <option value="11" data-value="rednessbumps">Redness / Bumps</option>
  <option value="15" data-value="sunspotsfreckles">Sunspots / Freckles</option>
  <option value="16" data-value="agingwrinkles">Aging / Wrinkles</option>
  <option value="17" data-value="dry-sensitive">Dry Sensitive</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery has a built in `data` to do what you want:

```
var abc = $(this).data('value')
```

However, you must find the selected option FIRST, then get its value.

```js
$("#category").change(function () {
   var selectedItem = $(this).val();
   var abc=$(this).find(':selected').data("value");
   console.log(abc)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category" name="category">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option value="50" data-value="akne">ACNE</option>
  <option value="11" data-value="rednessbumps">Redness / Bumps</option>
  <option value="15" data-value="sunspotsfreckles">Sunspots / Freckles</option>
  <option value="16" data-value="agingwrinkles">Aging / Wrinkles</option>
  <option value="17" data-value="dry-sensitive">Dry Sensitive</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `this` refer to `#category` that hasn't any `data-value` attribute. You should find selected option in it.

```
$(this).find(":selected").attr("data-value");
// Or
$(":selected", this).attr("data-value");
```

```js
$("#category").change(function () {
  var abc = $(":selected", this).data("value");
  console.log(abc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category" name="category">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option value="50" data-value="akne">ACNE</option>
  <option value="11" data-value="rednessbumps">Redness / Bumps</option>
  <option value="15" data-value="sunspotsfreckles">Sunspots / Freckles</option>
  <option value="16" data-value="agingwrinkles">Aging / Wrinkles</option>
  <option value="17" data-value="dry-sensitive">Dry Sensitive</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#category").change(function () {
   var selectedItem = $(this).val();
   var abc= $('option:selected', this).attr('data-value');
   console.log(abc,selectedItem);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category" name="category">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option value="50" data-value="akne">ACNE</option>
  <option value="11" data-value="rednessbumps">Redness / Bumps</option>
  <option value="15" data-value="sunspotsfreckles">Sunspots / Freckles</option>
  <option value="16" data-value="agingwrinkles">Aging / Wrinkles</option>
  <option value="17" data-value="dry-sensitive">Dry Sensitive</option>
</select>
```

Use `$('option:selected', this).attr('data-value');` or `$('option:selected', this).data('value');` to access attributes from selected `option`

Answer (score 0):

> This is the HTML

```
    <select class="form-control" type="text" onchange="set_bank_branches(this)" id="payment_bank_name" name="payment_bank_name" value="">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="ADB" data-min="16" data-max="16">AGRICULTURAL DEVELOPMENT BANK</option>
<option value="ACC" data-min="13" data-max="13">ACCESS BANK</option>
<option value="BOA" data-min="11" data-max="11">BANK OF AFRICA</option>
</select>
```

> This is the Javascript function that gets the data on the option

```
function set_bank_branches(x)
{

    // This is where I get the data on the option selected
    var minlength= $(x).find(":selected").attr("data-min");
    var maxlength= $(x).find(":selected").attr("data-min");
    alert("maxlength: " + maxlength + " -- minlength: " + minlength);

}
```