# jQuery how to select children elements the proper way

Tags: jquery

If I have the following html

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="item1"></div>
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="item3"></div>
</div>
```

What would be the proper way to select children of the parent div.

I have the following:

```
var $parent = $('#parent'),
$item1 = $('#item1',$parent),
$item2 = $('#item2',$parent),
$item3 = $('#item3',$parent);
```

or if

```
var $parent = $('#parent'),
$item1 = $parent.find('#item1'),
$item2 = $parent.find('#item2'),
$item3 = $parent.find('#item3');
```

is more correct. From my tests I think they both work, but just wondering what the standard convention is for this.

The reason I do not use a more direct single selector like $('#parent #item1') is the parent could change, or could be selected from a callback function, and I want to be able to select its children without directly knowing the id of the parent, but rather using a jquery object of the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery's [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function.

`$("#parent").children("div");`

Answer (score 0):

If possible, i would go for selecting the child elements with its Id because the Id will (should) be unique to an element.

I would prefer children method over find

```
 $('#parent').children("#item1);
```

children is faster than find method. Refer this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/648014/40521