# How can I use jquery to get the value of a child of a child that is in an adjacent tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, children

Starting from a particular `div` I want to use jquery to grab the value of the `input` tag in the next `div` block (two levels down). I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="firstClass1" id="firstID1"> // suppose I start from this element
    <div class="secondClass1" id="secondID1">
        <input value="myValue1"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="firstClass2" id="firstID2">
    <div class="secondClass2" id="secondID2">
        <input value="myValue2"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="firstClass3" id="firstID3">
    <div class="secondClass3" id="secondID3">
        <input value="myValue3"/>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

That is, if I start from `.firstClass1`, I want to get the value from `myValue2`. I have tried using the following jquery, but it doesn't work:

```
var nextID = $('.div#firstID1').next().find('input').val();
```

and

```
var nextID = $('.div#firstID1').next().next().val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missed a quotation mark, also remove the `dot` from `.div#firstID1`:

```
var nextID = $('div#firstID').next().find('input').val();
```

Comment: @AjayMohite you should also remove the `.` from div.

Comment: wow, I feel like an idiot. I tried so many different ways to try to get it to work. That was it. Thanks for having a better eye than me!

Answer (score 3):

This will help : http://jsfiddle.net/bQYZJ/

You had extra `.` dot as well as `id` was `firstID1` not `firstID` `:)` Rest I have tuned it for your need.

Hope this help,

**code**

```
var nextID = $('div#firstID1').next('div').find('input').val();
```

Comment: @Jashwant Hello hello, long time! Hope things are rocking! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `.div` with just `div`.

Just try with:

```
$('div[id^=firstID]').mouseenter(function(){
    var nextID = $(this).next().find('input').prop('value');
    alert( nextID ); // test it!
});
```

`$('div[id^=firstID]')` means "any div which ID starts with `firstID`", 
this will allow you to grab the 'next div input value' of any 'evented' element so you don't need to rewrite the code for ANY `firstID[N]` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can **also** use,

```
var nextID = $('div#firstID1 > div > input')
```

or

```
var nextID = $('div#firstID1').children().children()
```

or

```
var nextID = $('div#firstID1').children('div').children('input');
```

But (for reasons unknown to me), `find` works faster than `children` and `>` approach.

Comment: Yeah it is weird that `find` is faster than `children`. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7692401/145346) with some interesting observations.