# When using jquery's next() function to get the next element in a list, how do I get the first element after reaching the end of the list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Technically, this isn't for a 'list' (ul -> li), but for a series of `div` blocks inside a container `div`. I  have tried many different ways to try and achieve this, but none of them work. What happens is that when I get to the last element, and then click on my 'next button' it takes me to the SECOND element in the list, never the first element. This is generally the code I'm using:

```
<div class="wrapperClass">
<div class="myClass" id="ID1">
    <div class="anotherClass">
        <input value="myValue1"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="myClass" id="ID2">
    <div class="anotherClass">
        <input value="myValue2"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="myClass" id="ID3">
    <div class="anotherClass"">
        <input value="myValue3"/>
    </div>
</div>
...
</div>
```

and

```
var nextID = $('div#'+ID).next().find('input').val();
var lastID = $('div#'+ID+':last').find('input').val();

if( nextID == lastID )
{
    nextID = $('.wrapperClass').find('input:first').val();
}
// other code
```

Comment: The longest title I've ever seen!

Comment: `$('div#'+ID+':last')` doesn't make sense ids are unique and there should be no last element. you can try `$('.myClass:last')` instead.

Comment: I agree! I just edited the code, I forgot to add the 'wrapper' div. My jquery function receives a parameter called 'ID'. I've tried lot's of different things, such as using `$('.myClass:first').find('input').val(), etc. It always takes me back to the 2nd element.

Comment: the posted code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/RNrg2/

Comment: Could you show that JS in context, perhaps in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? How is `ID` set? I wouldn't be trying to select by id at all, e.g., if `this` is a particular input I'd be saying `$(this).closest('div.myClass').next().find('input')` (or similar).

Comment: Same question `:)` < might be > or < lil difference > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386628/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-get-the-value-of-a-child-of-a-child-that-is-in-an-adjace

Comment: What are you actually trying to do though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize my mistake(s). I should have written

```
if( currentID == lastID )
{
    // blah
}
```

It was also incorrect for me to write

```
$('div#'+ID+':last')
```

Since id's must be unique. Thanks 'undefined' (unnamed person who pointed that out). I'm clearly a newbie.