# Move background position on click event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to move the background position of an element when a certain div is clicked only I cant seem to get it working.

My jquery seems fine from the documentation?

```
$(this).children('ul li').css('background-position-x','100px');
```

Heres a jsfiddle demo...
http://jsfiddle.net/shqcu/

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of `children()`:

```
$(this).find("ul li").css("background-position-x", "100px");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/shqcu/1/

Comment: children is immediate "offspring" of the parent so your `<div>` might only have `<ul>` as "children" but has lots of little `<li>` grandchildren or descendents...`find()` gets all descendants

Comment: @Liam This is because a selector in `children` is used to *filter* children elements, but not to find elements among the descendants.

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter an element's background-position with jQuery alone. You need this plugin http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css('background-image','url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBFaoYPOnLv_EI4sGOisRrHUGhlHjJp7iY2A4RT1PKXAAPxx3f)');
```