# Find a control underneath parent in jQuery -- is this the cleanest way?

Tags: jquery

If I wanted to find an element on the page, I would use $('#Foo');

Now, I have a scenario where my 'this' context is a jQuery element. I would like to find an element underneath 'this.'

I am using:

```
$(this).find('#Foo');
```

I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a cleaner way of expressing this. If I wasn't in my this context, I might use something like $('#this #Foo'). It seems surprising that my jQuery selector query gets longer when I have an explicit reference to the 'this' jQuery element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off, since element ids are unique to the document, you don't need to find one within the context of another element.. but for a nice syntax, I like

$('.foo', this)  which will find all children with class "foo"

Comment: It will find all descendents which is different than children.

Comment: true, I stand corrected..

Comment: Everyone else was concerned about optimization. I was looking for this cool shorthand syntax for when I have reference to this. Accepting this answer because I learned $('.foo', this) works :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) is faster than [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
$(this).children('#Foo');
```

**Explanation**

Reason is, `.children()` only looks at the immediate children of the node, while `.find()` traverses the entire DOM below the node, so **`.children()` should be faster** given equivalent implementations. `find` uses native browser methods, however, while `children` uses JavaScript interpreted in the browser.  In my experiments there isn't much performance difference in typical cases.

**References**

1. [What is fastest children() or find() in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/648014/462627)
2. [Traversing `.children()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children#expr)
3. [Traversing `.find()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr)

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique, so the quickest way to select `#Foo` in jQuery would simply be

```
$('#Foo')
```

To answer your question,  the `.children()` method is faster than `.find()` in most browsers, and it works the same as long as you're dealing with direct descendants.

```
$(this).children('#Foo')
```

I put together a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/quickest-selectors) which demonstrates this. Keep in mind that in most cases the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: How come children is faster when dealing with direct descendants? I would expect find to perform a breadth-first search... the first level's iteration being the same as .children()'s ?

Comment: @SeanAnderson And then it continues down to every other level unnecessarily, wasting time looking where it will find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding an element by id, you shouldn't need to preselect $(this). Element ids should be unique. No two elements should have the same id. That said, if you're selecting by something else, like class, you'll need to use $(this).find(".myclass") to select subelements.