# Jquery: Accessing a tag element inside $(this)

Tags: jquery

```
<li><a href="home.html"> Home </a> </li>
<li> <a href="contact.html">Contact </a></li>

$('li').mouseenter( function() { 
    $(this).attr('a').css("color", "red");   
});
```

fails. I am trying to understand how to reach that a within that 'li'.  (not any 'li a')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as `a` is element not the attribute of current element.

```
$('li').mouseenter( function() { 
    $(this).find('a').css("color", "red");   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` is an element not an attribute, you can use `find` method:

```
$('li').mouseenter(function() { 
    $(this).find('a').css("color", "red"); 
    // or using $(selector, context):
    // $('a', this).css("color", "red"); 
});
```

However JavaScript doesn't work like CSS, you should change the color on `mouseleave` event, you can create a class and use `toggleClass` method:

```
.red {
   color: red;
}
```

```
$('li').hover(function() { 
    $(this).find('a').toggleClass('red');
});
```

And you can also use CSS (*lighter and faster*):

```
li:hover a {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `children` or `find` for this

```
$('li').mouseenter( function() { 
    $(this).children('a').css("color", "red");   
});
```

**Note:** `Children` only looks at the immediate children of the node, while `find` traverses the entire DOM below the node, so children should be faster given equivalent implementations. find uses native browser methods, however, while children uses JavaScript interpreted in the browser. In my experiments there isn't much performance difference in typical cases.

Copied from [What is fastest children() or find() in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way too:

```
$('li').mouseenter( function() { 
   $('a', this).css("color", "red");   
});
```