# Append value by data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, append, custom-data-attribute

I've got the following situation:

There is a table provided with the following data attribute `name` and `value`: `data-specificationattributename="Basiseenheid"` in the following table row:

```
<tr class="even" data-specificationattributename="Basiseenheid">
    <td class="a-left spec-namehide">
        Basiseenheid
    </td>     
    <td class="a-left spec-valuehide">
        KG 
    </td>   
</tr>
```

What I like is get the value (KG) on the basis of the data attribute and append this to the following `div` `"span.qty unit-result"`:

```
<div class="qty-unit">
    <span class="qty-unit-result"></span>
</div>
```

Hopefully someone can show me how to do this.

Comment: did you mean to get 'KG' when 'Basiseenheid' is passed to you that is present inside first td?

Answer (score 2):

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/42AWs/1/)**

```
var selector = $('[data-specificationattributename=Basiseenheid]');
var kgVal = selector.find('.spec-valuehide').text().trim();
$('.qty-unit-result').html(kgVal);
```

Or

```
var selector = $('[data-specificationattributename=Basiseenheid] .spec-valuehide');
var kgVal = selector.text().trim();
$('.qty-unit-result').html(kgVal);
```

EDIT:
**[jsPerf Test results](http://jsperf.com/selectorskrish2) between the two of them.**

Turns out .find() is around 16-18% slower than the space selector.

.find() - 24,035 Operations per second, 18% slower

merge selector - 29,501 Operations per second, fastest
[image]

Comment: You can merge your initial selector and .find() into one selector, given that your searching in the same direction.

Comment: @Prusprus - `find` tends to be faster than multi-level selectors.

Comment: AFAIK, one large selector gets pushed to javascript's querySelectorAll, while chaining breaks the selector into multiple functions. So for modern browsers, jquery will push the selector directly to js.

Comment: @guys - thanks for the comments .. I added both, Peace :)

Comment: @BlueBay - glad to help. please upvote all helpful answers & accept one of them.

Comment: @Prusprus - any performance test that I have ever seen has rated `$("SELECTOR_1").find("SELECTOR_2");` faster than `$("SELECTOR_1 SELECTOR_2");`

Comment: @Prusprus and talemyn - the performance topic caught me interesting. I did some jsperf test on them. Turns out Prusprus way is faster.

Comment: @BlueBay you might want to accept this answer. Krishna, thanks for the metrics. Not to discredit talemnyn, do you have your metrics to compare?

Comment: @Prusprus and Krishna - this jsperf test compares a 7 different selection approaches: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selectors-context/2  (from the last answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery).  In over 1000 runs, across different browsers, only a subset of Opera browsers shows significant speed using only a selector.  The `find()` approach is rarely beaten by anything but `children()`, which, of course, is only usable for immediate child selections.  Admittedly, a "selector + `find`" is not as fast as "context + `find`".

Comment: That's amazing, I would have never guess. Good job @talemyn. What I take away from this: 1) Performance is relative to its scenario/environment 2) Context, Context, Context: Can't hurt.

Comment: Before I saw that, I had a hard time believing it too.   :)   Even before seeing it, though, when I would run an occasional performance test just to check, `find` kept winning out.  I think for me I assumed that because it looks more efficient, it should preform more efficiently too.   :D

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can get the KG with this command :

```
var fst= $( ".spec-valuehide" ).html();
```

Then append it into another width this command:

```
$( ".qty-unit-result" ).append(fst);
```

see : 
http://api.jquery.com/append/
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: but thats not what OP wanted though. He wants the value where there is a specific data attribute to the row.

Comment: yes, ur right , misunderstand .

Answer (score 1):

```
find_value($key){
    return $('table tr[data-specificationattributename='+$key+'] td.spec-value-hide').html().trim();
}

$('div.qty-unit span.qty-unit-result').html(find_value('Basiseenheid'));
```