# Trouble with dropdown submenus in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm making drop-down sub-menus with jquery, but when I hover over any of the main navigation links, all of the sub-menus drop down. I believe I need to do something with `this()` but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xzN5G/

Here's my HTML

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="mainli"><a href="" class="selected">Home</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>s1111111</li>
                <li>a2222222</li>
                <li>g3333333</li>
                <li>y4444444</li>
            </ul>
        </li>    
        <li class="mainli"><a href="album.html">My Photos</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>11111111</li>
                <li>22222222</li>
                <li>33333333</li>
                <li>44444444</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mainli"><a href="travel.html">My Travel</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>aaaaaaaaaa</li>
                <li>bbbbbbbbbb</li>
                <li>cccccccccc</li>
                <li>dddddddddd</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mainli"><a href="aboutwork.html">About Work</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>rgre1111</li>
                <li>estg22</li>
                <li>thser3333</li>
                <li>rtyr4444</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mainli"><a href="portfolio.html">My Portfolio</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>qqqqqqqq</li>
                <li>tttttttt</li>
                <li>ppppppppp</li>
                <li>yyyyyyyyyy</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mainli"><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>99999999</li>
                <li>88888888</li>
                <li>77777777</li>
                <li>66666666</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mainli").hover(function() {
        $(".submenu").slideDown("medium");
    }, function () {
        $(".submenu").slideUp("medium");
    })
});
```

Comment: By defualt they should be expanded?

Comment: you might be able to get away with `this` here. `$(this).slideDown("medium");

Comment: Are you aware that hover is dead? None of your mobile users will be able to use this menu.

Comment: @cpburnz Thanks for tidying up my code, but that doesn't really help me. :)

Comment: @Rahil Wazir when I hover over one, that one should expand

Comment: @Mallanaga that won't work!

Comment: oh? see below, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for the `.submenu` inside `$(this)`, the method `find()` will do this for you. `children()` will work as well in your case, as long as the `.submenu` is a direct child of `this()`. `find()` on the other hand searches within all descendants (aka children, grandchildren etc..)

According to [What is fastest children() or find() in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery) there's no great deal of difference in terms of speed between both functions

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // $(".submenu").slideUp("medium");
    $(".mainli").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".submenu").slideDown("medium");
    },

    function () {
        $(this).find(".submenu").slideUp("medium");
    });
});
```

I tried this out in your fiddle and it worked, you might want to uncomment that line `$(".submenu").slideUp("medium");` so that all menus start closed.

Comment: I don't think it's ideal to hide the `.submenu` with JS like that. It's likely to cause a flash of the visible menu while the page is loading.

Comment: Thanks. If you add a fiddle it will always be more appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method, and set your `.submenu` to `display: none` so it's hidden at first:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mainli").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".submenu").slideDown("medium");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find(".submenu").slideUp("medium");
  }
  );
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VAYxh/3/).

Comment: Is `find` preferred to `children` in this context?  I said `children` in my answer but `find` may be more efficient or handle certain cases better.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably better ways to do this but given minimal changes to your code, the following should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submenu').slideUp();
    $(".mainli").hover(function() {
        $(this).children('.submenu').slideDown("medium");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).children('.submenu').slideUp("medium");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VAYxh/4/

Comment: Just one more question. Being that i have content underneath the menus, how do I get that content to ignore the sub-menus dropping down on them?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xzN5G/4/

`$(".submenu", this)`

That should do it for you. Also, in your CSS, you need to have `.submenu { display: none; }`

Comment: Your comment contain different syntax than your answer read above :)

Comment: Granted. I use the comments to get OP to start thinking. I use answers to actually solve the problem.

Comment: I replied to your comment: (oh? see below, please.)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally hide the sub-menus by default and then check if they are hidden on hover, if they are hidden then slide them down otherwise just use hide.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzN5G/6/).

Updated JS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mainli").hover(function () {
        var target = $(this).find('.submenu');
        if (target.is(':hidden')) {
            target.slideDown("medium");
        } else {
            target.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Added CSS

```
ul.submenu {
    float: right;
    display:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```