# Jquery get Second child that is type div selector

Tags: jquery

How can i select in the most easiest way the second occurrence of element type div in a given element(parent).

For example:

```
div
   span
   div
   pre
   div ==i want this ==
/div
```

Comment: how about div > div:eq(1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the parent div has a class of *parent* for example:

```
$("div.parent").find("div").eq(1);
```

Comment: Depends how complex your DOM tree is. See related question [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery). This is assuming you don't have nested divs, and so `.find()` would actually be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `div:eq()`

```
$("#parent_div div:eq(1)")
```

Example

```
<div id="parent_div">
    <span></span>
    <div>1</div>
    <span></span>
    <div>2</div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var test = $("#parent_div div:eq(1)").text(); //eq(1) is 2nd div
    alert(test);
</script>
```