# check element has some element inside using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can do like `if($('.div').find('.someelem').length == 0` .. to check whether .someelem is available inside the div,

but what if I want to check for any element? I don't know what is the class within.

```
<div>
</div>
```

^ Check above div contain something or not.

Comment: you want to check whether it has some element or whether it has any text or element like `<div>some</div>`

Comment: @ArunPJohny tags like `<div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **faster** way to do it is using `.find()` cause it will not trigger the somewhat *expensive* jQuery's Sizzle Selector Library:

```
if( !$(".div").find(">")[0] ){
    // Maybe has text, but has absolutely no children Elements.
}
```

If you want to be more specific about your selectors, instead of using `">"` (*any* immediate child) you can use `"div"` aswell, to restrict your search to `DIV` Elements only.

---

You can also check with "if *is empty*"

```
$(".div:empty").someMethodYouWant(); // Do some stuff on empty elements. (Really empty)
```

or

```
if( $(".div").is(":empty")  ){
    // Has no elements and no text
}
```

note that the above will yield `false` if you have just some text (means it's not empty).

If you rather want to go for immediate children `>` elements

```
if( !$(".div:has(>)").length ){
    // Maybe has text, but has absolutely no children Elements.
}
```

or also:

```
if( !$(".div:has(>)")[0] ){
    // Maybe has text, but has absolutely no children Elements.
}
```

or even simpler:

```
if( !$(".div >")[0] ){
    // Maybe has text, but has absolutely no children Elements.
}
```

Comment: holy cow great answer!

Comment: You can also use [$(selector).children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to simply see if an element has any children but it checks only for **immediate children**. [Anyway find() is faster than children()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery).