# Cannot select input jquery

Tags: jquery

It's a very simple question, but I dont know exactly how to get from .

```
<div>
    <input>
</div>
<p id="pepe"></p>
```

The following :

```
$("#pepe").prev()
```

gives me the div, how I get the first child (input)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've seen `prev()` gets the previous sibling element. To get the `input` from there you need to use `find()`, along with `:first` assuming there will be multiple within your actual working HTML:

```
$("#pepe").prev().find('input:first');
```

Comment: wouldn't $.children() would be more efficient? as his input is one level down

Comment: @godmode [What is fastest children() or find() in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

`$("#pepe").prev()` is getting you the `<div>`

try `$("#pepe").prev().children('input');`

Answer (score 1):

In your code `.prev()` point out the div element not the input. if you have search input means use `.find()` in jquery

```
$("#pepe").prev().find('input')
```