# Display div based on select value

Tags: jquery

I have a 5 sets of divs with common class names. I need to display child divs based on the value of the select element, which is also under a child div. But absolutely nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.item-chooser').each(function() {
  var media = $(this).val();
  if (media == 'fontawesome') {
    $(this).parent('.cta-block').children('.cta-fa-icon').slideDown();
  } else if (media == 'image') {
    $(this).parent('.cta-block').children('.cta-image-upload').slideDown();
  }
  $(this).change(function() {
    var media = $(this).val();
    if (media == 'fontawesome') {
      $(this).parent('.cta-block-item-wrap').children('.cta-image-upload').slideUp();
      $(this).parent('.cta-block-item-wrap').children('.cta-fa-icon').slideDown();
    } else if (media == 'image') {
      $(this).parent('.cta-block-item-wrap').children('.cta-fa-icon').slideUp();
      $(this).parent('.cta-block-item-wrap').children('.cta-image-upload').slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cta-block-item-wrap {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.cta-image-upload,
.cta-fa-icon {
  display: none;
}
.cta-block-item-wrap > label {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cta-block">
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-icon-image">
    <label for="item-chooser">FA Icon/Image:</label>
    <select class="item-chooser" name="item-chooser">
      <option value="fontawesome">FontAwesome Icon</option>
      <option value="image">Image</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-image-upload">
    <label for="block-image">Upload Image:</label>
    <input name="block-image" class="block-image" type="text" value="">
    <input type="button" class="cta-insert-image button button-primary button-large" value="Upload">
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-fa-icon">
    <label for="fa-icon-class">Choose FA Icon:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fa-icon-class" class="fa-icon-class" value="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cta-block">
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-icon-image">
    <label for="item-chooser">FA Icon/Image:</label>
    <select class="item-chooser" name="item-chooser">
      <option value="fontawesome">FontAwesome Icon</option>
      <option value="image">Image</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-image-upload">
    <label for="block-image">Upload Image:</label>
    <input name="block-image" class="block-image" type="text" value="">
    <input type="button" class="cta-insert-image button button-primary button-large" value="Upload">
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-fa-icon">
    <label for="fa-icon-class">Choose FA Icon:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fa-icon-class" class="fa-icon-class" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give us the css, please. I will setup a working fiddle.

Comment: @Stanimir, there's not much CSS as of now. Edited the question and added the existing CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**, you are using [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to traverse from `.item-chooser` to `.cta-block`. But `parent()` only travels up a single level in the DOM and `.cta-block` is not the direct parent of `.item-chooser`. I suggest using [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) or [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead.

> .parent() only travels a single level up the DOM tree

I have also replaced [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) with [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) for flexibility and because [it may to be a bit faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery) in your context , but your `children()` selector works, too.

```js
$(this).closest('.cta-block').find('.cta-fa-icon').slideDown();
```

**Second**, you are iterating through each `.item-chooser` to set the initial state *and* bind an event listener. I suggest simplifying things by binding a "change" event handler and then triggering a change:

```
$('.item-chooser').on('change',function() { .. }).trigger('change');
```

**Third**, you are not sliding up one option when you slide down another. It seems that you'd want to hide the file input when you show the icon input, and vice versa:

```
$(this).closest('.cta-block').find('.cta-fa-icon').slideDown();
$(this).closest('.cta-block').find('.cta-image-upload').slideUp();
```

---

See my demonstration below:

```js
$('.item-chooser').on('change', function() {
  var media = $(this).val();
  if (media == 'fontawesome') {
    $(this).closest('.cta-block').find('.cta-fa-icon').slideDown();
    $(this).closest('.cta-block').find('.cta-image-upload').slideUp();
  } else if (media == 'image') {
    $(this).closest('.cta-block').find('.cta-image-upload').slideDown();
    $(this).closest('.cta-block').find('.cta-fa-icon').slideUp();
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
.cta-block-item-wrap {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.cta-image-upload,
.cta-fa-icon {
  display: none;
}
.cta-block-item-wrap > label {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cta-block">
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-icon-image">
    <label for="item-chooser">FA Icon/Image:</label>
    <select class="item-chooser" name="item-chooser">
      <option value="fontawesome">FontAwesome Icon</option>
      <option value="image">Image</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-image-upload">
    <label for="block-image">Upload Image:</label>
    <input name="block-image" class="block-image" type="text" value="">
    <input type="button" class="cta-insert-image button button-primary button-large" value="Upload">
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-fa-icon">
    <label for="fa-icon-class">Choose FA Icon:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fa-icon-class" class="fa-icon-class" value="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cta-block">
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-icon-image">
    <label for="item-chooser">FA Icon/Image:</label>
    <select class="item-chooser" name="item-chooser">
      <option value="fontawesome">FontAwesome Icon</option>
      <option value="image">Image</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-image-upload">
    <label for="block-image">Upload Image:</label>
    <input name="block-image" class="block-image" type="text" value="">
    <input type="button" class="cta-insert-image button button-primary button-large" value="Upload">
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-fa-icon">
    <label for="fa-icon-class">Choose FA Icon:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fa-icon-class" class="fa-icon-class" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT

Alternatively, you could name the classes of your divs to correspond with your select values. Then you can simplify your code even further by removing the `if` statement.

```html
<div class="cta-option cta-option-image"></div>
<div class="cta-option cta-option-fontawesome"></div>
```

```js
$container.find('.cta-option').slideUp();
$container.find('.cta-option-'+option).stop(true).slideDown();
```

See the working demo below:

```js
$('.item-chooser').on('change', function() {
  
  var $this=$(this),
      $container=$this.closest('.cta-block'),
      option = $this.val();
      
  
  $container.find('.cta-option').slideUp();
  $container.find('.cta-option-'+option).stop(true).slideDown();

}).trigger('change');
```

```css
.cta-block-item-wrap {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.cta-option {
  display: none;
}
.cta-block-item-wrap > label {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cta-block">
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-icon-image">
    <label for="item-chooser">FA Icon/Image:</label>
    <select class="item-chooser" name="item-chooser">
      <option value="fontawesome">FontAwesome Icon</option>
      <option value="image">Image</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-option cta-option-image">
    <label for="block-image">Upload Image:</label>
    <input name="block-image" class="block-image" type="text" value="">
    <input type="button" class="cta-insert-image button button-primary button-large" value="Upload">
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-option cta-option-fontawesome">
    <label for="fa-icon-class">Choose FA Icon:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fa-icon-class" class="fa-icon-class" value="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cta-block">
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-icon-image">
    <label for="item-chooser">FA Icon/Image:</label>
    <select class="item-chooser" name="item-chooser">
      <option value="fontawesome">FontAwesome Icon</option>
      <option value="image">Image</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-option cta-option-image">
    <label for="block-image">Upload Image:</label>
    <input name="block-image" class="block-image" type="text" value="">
    <input type="button" class="cta-insert-image button button-primary button-large" value="Upload">
  </div>
  <div class="cta-block-item-wrap cta-option cta-option-fontawesome">
    <label for="fa-icon-class">Choose FA Icon:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fa-icon-class" class="fa-icon-class" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It's working for me just as I want it. Thanks again. And, I got another question, can you please have a look at this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980742/clone-a-div-based-on-input-value Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchy is wrong when you use `.children()`. You should use `.siblings()`.

`cta-image-upload` and `cta-fa-icon` are siblings of `cta-block-item-wrap` (item_chooser's parent), not children.

Ex `$(this).parent('.cta-block-item-wrap').siblings('.cta-image-upload').slideUp();`