# Hide a div unless I choose a category

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a category filter div (block_container) which shows everything in the div by default, the thing is that I want this div to be hidden unless I  click on a category.

In other words, I want to add the ".hide" class to the ".block_container" div as long as I don't choose a category from the "container" div.

Category selector div:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.category_item').click(function() {
    var category = $(this).attr('id');

    if (category == 'all') {
      $('.gameCard').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.gameCard').removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $('.gameCard').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <p class="category_item" id="car"><img class="icons" src="icons/car.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="cooking"><img class="icons" src="icons/cooking.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="shooting"><img class="icons" src="icons/shooting.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="racing"><img class="icons" src="icons/racing.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="dressup"><img class="icons" src="icons/dressup.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="puzzle"><img class="icons" src="icons/puzzle.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="kids"><img class="icons" src="icons/kids.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="strategy"><img class="icons" src="icons/strategy.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="action"><img class="icons" src="icons/action.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="multiplayer"><img class="icons" src="icons/multiplayer.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="sport"><img class="icons" src="icons/sport.png" alt=""></p>
</div>

<!-- the div that I want to be hidden by default: -->

<div class="block_container">
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard car"><img class="game_item car" src="gamescat/carGames/asettoCorsa.jpg">
      <div class="gameName">Ascetto Corsa</div>
      <div class="gameDesc">Racing simulator</div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard action"><img class="game_item action" src="gamescat/actionGames/cosmicBreak.jpg">
      <div class="gameName"> Cosmic Break</div>
      <div class="gameDesc">A Cosmic Universe!</div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/4stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard cooking"><img class="game_item cooking" src="gamescat/cookGames/calico.jpg">
      <div class="gameName">Calico</div>
      <div class="gameDesc">A day-in-the-life game! </div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard dressup"><img class="game_item dressup" src="gamescat/dressupGames/kidGilantes.jpg">
      <div class="gameName">Kid Gilantes</div>
      <div class="gameDesc">Your own style</div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard kids"><img class="game_item kids" src="gamescat/kidsGames/bloons.jpg">
      <div class="gameName">Bloons</div>
      <div class="gameDesc"></div>
      <div class="gameDesc">Family Friendly Battles</div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard multiplayer"><img class="game_item multiplayer" src="gamescat/multiGames/astelliaRoyal.jpg">
      <div class="gameName">Astellia Royal</div>
      <div class="gameDesc">Classic 3D MMORPG</div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/5stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard puzzle"><img class="game_item puzzle" src="gamescat/puzzleGames/dungeon2.jpg">
      <div class="gameName">Dungeon 2</div>
      <div class="gameDesc">spectacular puzzle game</div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/4stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard racing"><img class="game_item racing" src="gamescat/raceGames/cubeRacer.jpg">
      <div class="gameName">Cube Racer</div>
      <div class="gameDesc"> racing game with cubes!</div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard shooting"><img class="game_item shooting" src="gamescat/shootingGames/bioshock.jpg">
      <div class="gameName">Bioshock</div>
      <div class="gameDesc">A City in the Sky...</div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard sport"><img class="game_item sport" src="gamescat/sportGames/dirtRally.jpg">
      <div class="gameName">Dirty Rally</div>
      <div class="gameDesc">An authentic rally game</div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/2stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html">
    <div class="gameCard strategy"><img class="game_item strategy" src="gamescat/strategyGames/ageOfEmpires.jpg">
      <div class="gameName">Age Of Empires</div>
      <div class="gameDesc">Real-time strategy game</div>
      <div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display div based on select value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971384/display-div-based-on-select-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add the class `hide` in the div.gameCard-tags. The rest works as expected:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.category_item').click(function() {
    var category = $(this).attr('id');

    if (category == 'all') {
      $('.gameCard').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.gameCard').removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $('.gameCard').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="container">
  <p class="category_item" id="all">all</p>
  <p class="category_item" id="car">car<img class="icons" src="icons/car.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="cooking">cooking<img class="icons" src="icons/cooking.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="shooting">shooting<img class="icons" src="icons/shooting.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="racing">racing<img class="icons" src="icons/racing.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="dressup">dressup<img class="icons" src="icons/dressup.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="puzzle">puzzle<img class="icons" src="icons/puzzle.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="kids">kids<img class="icons" src="icons/kids.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="strategy">strategy<img class="icons" src="icons/strategy.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="action">action<img class="icons" src="icons/action.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="multiplayer">multiplayer<img class="icons" src="icons/multiplayer.png" alt=""></p>
  <p class="category_item" id="sport">sport<img class="icons" src="icons/sport.png" alt=""></p>
</div>

<div class="block_container"> 
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide car"><img class="game_item car" src="gamescat/carGames/asettoCorsa.jpg"><div class="gameName">Ascetto Corsa</div><div class="gameDesc">Racing simulator</div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div></div></a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide action"><img class="game_item action" src="gamescat/actionGames/cosmicBreak.jpg"><div class="gameName"> Cosmic Break</div><div class="gameDesc">A Cosmic Universe!</div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/4stars.png"></div></div></a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide cooking"><img class="game_item cooking" src="gamescat/cookGames/calico.jpg"><div class="gameName">Calico</div><div class="gameDesc">A day-in-the-life game! </div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div></div></a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide dressup"><img class="game_item dressup" src="gamescat/dressupGames/kidGilantes.jpg"><div class="gameName">Kid Gilantes</div><div class="gameDesc">Your own style</div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div></div></a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide kids"><img class="game_item kids" src="gamescat/kidsGames/bloons.jpg"><div class="gameName">Bloons</div><div class="gameDesc"></div><div class="gameDesc">Family Friendly Battles</div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div></div></a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide multiplayer"><img class="game_item multiplayer" src="gamescat/multiGames/astelliaRoyal.jpg"><div class="gameName">Astellia Royal</div><div class="gameDesc">Classic 3D MMORPG</div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/5stars.png"></div></div></a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide puzzle"><img class="game_item puzzle" src="gamescat/puzzleGames/dungeon2.jpg"><div class="gameName">Dungeon 2</div><div class="gameDesc">spectacular puzzle game</div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/4stars.png"></div></div></a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide racing"><img class="game_item racing" src="gamescat/raceGames/cubeRacer.jpg"><div class="gameName">Cube Racer</div><div class="gameDesc"> racing game with cubes!</div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div></div></a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide shooting"><img class="game_item shooting" src="gamescat/shootingGames/bioshock.jpg"><div class="gameName">Bioshock</div><div class="gameDesc">A City in the Sky...</div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div></div></a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide sport"><img class="game_item sport" src="gamescat/sportGames/dirtRally.jpg"><div class="gameName">Dirty Rally</div><div class="gameDesc">An authentic rally game</div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/2stars.png"></div></div></a>
  <a href="gamenotavailable.html"><div class="gameCard hide strategy"><img class="game_item strategy" src="gamescat/strategyGames/ageOfEmpires.jpg"><div class="gameName">Age Of Empires</div><div class="gameDesc">Real-time strategy game</div><div><img class="starsImg" src="stars/3stars.png"></div></div></a>
</div>
```