# Using jQuery on the select class not all the divs with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not really sure how to phrase that in the title. Anyways, what I'm saying is that I have three divs with the same class name. I want to add a mouseover function that only works on the select div, not all of them at once. For example :(https://jsfiddle.net/1y2jw2y0/) this makes all the divs show/hide, I only want the selected one to act on the jQuery function.

Html:

```
<div class="box">
  <p class="show">Show</p>
  <p class="hide">hide</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="show">Show</p>
  <p class="hide">hide</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="show">Show</p>
  <p class="hide">hide</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').mouseover(function() {
    $('.hide').show();
    $('.show').hide();
  });
  $('.box').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.hide').hide();
    $('.show').show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` to target the "selected" element, then select the child with [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children('.hide').show();
    $(this).children('.show').hide();
  });
  $('.box').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('.hide').hide();
    $(this).children('.show').show();
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zb5woj2c/)

#### Edited, to outline the performance issues brought up:

For basic details about the difference between `find` and `children`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/648014/264802) is a good resource.

In this case, I found `.find()` to be faster as a whole, usually ~`.2ms`.

After extensive testing, It appears there is very little, or **no difference between using `find()`, or using `$('.selector', this)`**

Overall, the results were similar. In some cases, it appears `$('.selector', this)` is slower, in others `find()`.

However, `find` does give you extra functionality that cannot be achieved with `$('.selector', this)`, such as a direct child selector: `.selector > .anotherone`, or caching the jQuery object to save resources.

### Summary: There isn't much difference, it all depends on your case, and what you prefer.

Comment: This is perfect. I'll accept this once it allows me to. Thank you!

Comment: @Jacob, Isn't find(), children() are slow comparing to direct selector $('.selector', this) ? Those are calling another jquery API if i'm not wrong.

Comment: @JeradRutnam For this specific case, then a definite *maybe*. I profiled both functions, and the results were close, within a fraction of a millisecond, usually with the "direct select" coming out about 1/10 to 2/10 of a millisecond faster. However, using `children` or `find` allows more diversity in your selector, such as selecting only direct children of the element.

Comment: @JacobGray, The same thing happening to me. could you tell me, the sandbox link- https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-lamport-9x4l6, 
 https://9x4l6.csb.app/

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all in CSS:

```
.box:hover .hide {
  display: block;
}

.box:hover .show {
  display: none;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zy2Ny/

If you really want to do it in JavaScript, simply use `$(this)` and `find()`:

More [information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/648014/264802) about whether `children()` or `find()` is faster.

```js
$(".box").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find(".hide").show();
    $(this).find(".show").hide();
});

$(".box").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".hide").hide();
    $(this).find(".show").show();
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxes">

  <div class="box">
    <p class="show">Show</p>
    <p class="hide">Hide</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p class="show">Show</p>
    <p class="hide">Hide</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p class="show">Show</p>
    <p class="hide">Hide</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1y2jw2y0/5/

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help. This is definitely what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Add a 'this' along with the selector,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').mouseover(function() {
        $('.hide', this).show();
        $('.show', this).hide();
    });
    $('.box').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.hide', this).hide();
        $('.show', this).show();
    });
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1y2jw2y0/6/

So basically you have to select the child selector of the mouse hovered element instead.

NOTE:- You can do this using find() & children() jquery API's as well. But it's bit slower than selecting directly.

And why not doing with pure css? See the example below,

```
.box {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
.hide,
.box:hover > .show {
   display: none;
}
.box:hover > .hide {
   display: block;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1y2jw2y0/3/

Answer (score 0):

Change your syntax to

`$('.box').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.hide').show();
    $(this).find('.show').hide();
  });`

Just navigate from the current element which trigerred the event to its child elements using `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your selector is targeting all of the divs with that class name in the document. You need to limit the scope to just the divs inside of the box you care about. One way to do this would be

```
$(this).find('.hide').show()
```

Instead of

```
$(".hide").show();
```

See here https://jsfiddle.net/1y2jw2y0/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can see: `$('.box')` select all `.box` div.
So that `$('.hide')` select all `.hide` p => when you click on a box, all `.hide` p are affected.
You can fix as following code:

```
$(this).select('.hide').hide()
$(this).select('.show').show()
```