# Expand Only the Child Div Within Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to only show a child div when the parent div's text is shown, instead of all the other divs with the same name.  Imagine four div's with classes of "lead" and within those leads, there is a normaldiv child.  Rather than open all the childs in other lead divs, I only want the one child within each lead.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">1</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">2</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">3</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">4</div></div>
```

**jQuery - this expands all normal divs**

```
$(".lead").click(function() {
  $(".normaldiv").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

**Tested:**

```
$(this).parent().children(".normaldiv").slideToggle("slow");
```

The tested one I thought would grab all the children within the parent div and only expand those on a click.  However, nothing shows up on a click event.

Comment: Is the second example enclosed in a click handler like the first?

Comment: Why not just try `$(this).children(".normaldiv").slideToggle("slow")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grab only the children not the parent children

```js
$(".lead").click(function() {
//  $(".normaldiv").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).children(".normaldiv").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">1</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">2</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">3</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">4</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).find(".normaldiv")` inside your *click listener* to select *only* the `normaldiv` inside the `lead` element - see demo below:

```js
$(".lead").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".normaldiv").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">1</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">2</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">3</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">4</div></div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it and your answer may be better depending on OP context

Comment: as another note [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery) claims `find` is faster than `children` so you may consider accepting this answer over mine

Comment: @happymacarts that's a valid point as `normaldiv`s are *direct* children...

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the *children* of the `.lead` elements that you are selecting.

What you are doing currently in the second example is selecting the parent of the `.lead` element (some container element), and then trying to select `.normaldiv` out of *its* children (which are only `.lead` elements).

```js
$(".lead").click(function() {
  $(this).children(".normaldiv").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.lead {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">1</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">2</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">3</div></div>
<div class="lead"><div class="normaldiv">4</div></div>
```

<sup>Note: CSS added for better visibility.</sup>