# What is the easiest way to get the id of a child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an up-vote button that has an child element with a dynamic id. How can I fetch the id of that child element?

I'm trying to add a voting feature to a blog site, and each blog has a unique ID that I need for the ajax call to log the vote in the database and also to update the vote tally in the html.

```js
$(".plus").click(function() {
    var myvar = $(".plus").find("h4");
    console.log(myvar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='plus'>
    <h4>up</h4>
    <h3 id='{{blog.id}}'>0</h3>
</button>
```

Comment: it's best to make snippets so people can copy your example and return a live one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can use this to get the child element's id:

```
$(".plus").click(function() {
    var myvar = $(this).find("h3")[0].id;
    console.log(myvar);
});
```

Yet i feel that if you change your markup a little that can also be possible with some `data-*` attributes:

```js
$('.plus').click(function(){
   // jquery version
   var blogId = $(this).data('blogId');
   console.log("jq .data() version::::", blogId);
   
   // js version
   var blgId = this.dataset.blogId;
   console.log("js .dataset version::::", blgId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='plus' data-blog-id='{{blog.id}}'>
   <h4>up</h4>
   <h3 id='{{blog.id}}'>0</h3>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided you want to get the id of h3 element and print it out in myvar
[Check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/9ktx6z9q/)

```
$(".plus").click(function(){
     var myvar = $( ".plus" ).find( "h3" ).attr("id");
     console.log(myvar);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery ***`.children()`*** will be the best option:-

```js
$(".plus").click(function(){
     var myvar = $( ".plus" ).children( "h3" ).attr('id');
     console.log(myvar);
     var myvar1 = $( ".plus" ).children( "h4" ).attr('id');
     console.log(myvar1);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='plus'>
     <h4 id="h4_id">up</h4>
     <h3 id='h3_id'>0</h3>
 </button>
```

***Why `.children()` is best in your case***:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/648014/4248328

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this.

```
$(".plus").click(function() {
 var myvar = $(this).find("h3").attr("id");
 alert(myvar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `.plus` items and want to get the `id` of each one on click, you can use the `this` context.

```js
$(".plus").click(function() {
    var myvar = $(this).find("h4").text();
    var myid = $(this).find("h3").attr("id");
    console.log(myvar, myid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='plus'>
    <h4>up</h4>
    <h3 id='id_1'>0</h3>
</button>

<button class='plus'>
    <h4>down</h4>
    <h3 id='id_2'>0</h3>
</button>
```

With this code, when you click a `.plus` button, it will look itself for the value of the `<h4>` snippet and the id of the `<h3>`.

Using a `$(".plus")` selector instead of `this` inside the click function will select ALL the buttons in the page when you click one, and the `attr()` method will return only the first ID instead of the current one.