# Jquery .each iteration accessing this subcontents

Tags: jquery, arrays, foreach

I would like to search for all list items and display only those that contain a certain phrase.

I however have placed the contents in a span.
Meaning that my list looks a bit like this:

```
<ul class="sortable">
<li><span>search keywords here</span>A lot of code possibly here. Some divs and some other elements</li>
</ul>
```

And I would like more or less use the following code to filter.

```
var filter = $('#search_page_query').val(), count = 0;    

$(".sortable li").each(function () {

    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut();


    } else {
        $(this).show();
        count++;
    }
});
```

This however would only work if the list item contains directly the search keywords.

That's not the case. I should search the list item with something like:

```
$(this + 'span').text()
```

But this is of-course incorrect. But I have no clue how to access the span contents correctly.
I hope that anyone could shed me a light on how it's done.

Thanks In Advance

---

Solved by **@RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi**

### The solution is

Instead of :

```
$(this).text()
```

use :

```
$(this).children('span').text()
```

Full code :

```
var filter = $('#search_page_query').val(), count = 0;    

$(".sortable li").each(function () {

    if ($(this).children('span').text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut();


    } else {
        $(this).show();
        count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried with `$(this).children('span')` ?

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi thanks!!! that worked!!! If you add is as an answer I can accept it! Don't know if you get any extra reputation that way! But if so. :D Thnx!

Comment: @AlexHakkenberg thank you for reputations from you! I've answered. Do your favor.  :-)

Comment: Instead of answering your question in your question, please move it to an answer below, and mark that as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to select a children of current DOM Element use `$(this).children()` function.

https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: There are many other ways to achieve this, and you might be better off using `$(this).find(">span").text()` or `$(">span", this).text()` rather than `.children()`.   But it's mostly micro managing. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27234084/2181514